# Issue printing UITextField Value

Tags: ios, swift

I have a `UITextField` on my storyboard and have an `outlet` to it in my controller.

`@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!`

I've created an action (`Editing Changed)` for the `UITextField`. For now, I'm trying to print out the value as the value is changed but it is giving me the following error :

> String interpolation produces a debug description of an optional value

Action Code :

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    print("The value is : \(textField.text)")
}
```

Kind of confused why I'm having this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` property of a text field is an optional, you have to unwrap the optional.

By the way you don't need the outlet, the `sender` parameter represents the text field

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    print("The value is : \(sender.text!)")
}
```

You don't even need String Interpolation, you can also write

```
print("The value is : ", sender.text!)
```

Comment: `UITextField text` will never return `nil`. It's documented to return `""`. Even if you set it to `nil` and then read the value, you will get `""`. This is a case where a force-unwrap is perfectly safe and much simpler.

Comment: I cannot imagine that Apple provides this inconsistency. Thanks, answer updated.

Comment: What inconsistency are you referring to?

Comment: The inconsistency to declare the property as optional but in practice it's a non-optional

Comment: It's probably a holdover from the original Objective-C API. If the API were designed from scratch with only Swift, it probably wouldn't be optional.

Comment: Yes, that's most likely the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You should force unwrap the value of text field

```
print("The value is : \(textField.text!)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

```
@IBAction func editingChanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
    print("The value is : \(sender.text)")
}
```

The function should recognize your textfield as the sender.

Comment: This will give the same warning message.